# Creating Tabs with jQuery but display content at the top

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've tried a few tab scripts but I think I'm looking for something more specific.

Basically I want something that shows a div and hides all others just like tabs.

Something very similar to this

http://jsfiddle.net/6UcDR/2/

But I want to be able to use something other than buttons. I will have a set up images lined up horizontally like a gallery. When one image is clicked some content in another div tag is displayed above it right in the middle. When another image is clicked, the one that was being displayed his hidden while the other is shown. Almost exactly like how it's being done at that jsfiddle demo.

However, I want to be able to use some type of div IDs / classes to connect the images with the content ... so

`<div id="blahblah"> Related Content Here </div><div id="blahblah"> Image Here </div>`

or something like this

`<div id="content123" class="tab_content" style="display: block;">
content here
<li class="active"><a href="#content123" rel="episodelist">Episode List</a></li>`

This would make it really easy for me to put into a php loop where I can pull out multiple images and it's content by using image IDs and so on.

Again, I want the content that's being displayed above the link or image that I'm going to have.

So it would look something like this ...

```
            Dynamic Content Displayed

Image1     Image2     Image3    Image4    Image5
```

This dynamic content would switch depending on the image that is clicked.

If someone could help, it would be great!

Comment: you can replace the buttons with any element, just needs to have the same ID.

Comment: How would I go about doing that when the IDs are originally different. That's why i'm confused.

Comment: replace the buttons with any element, but assign the ids they have now, different id for each ofc

Comment: Shouldn't the IDs match the ones in the div? I don't quite understand why the IDs are different. I've tried this code and it didn't work for me :(

Comment: the buttons are controls. the divs are shown/hidden. The first function in your js means "Click id=w, hide Ids b,c,d, show id a. for each button there is a function telling it what to do when clicked, in this case which divs to show or hide.

Comment: How could I make it so the jQuery / JavaScript doesn't look at the id of the actual div but instead which is clicked and making it so the image and content div ids are the same. Or are we able to use php in within javascript to define the ids ... ?

Comment: in jquery you can use all sorts of selectors, classes, elements, even parnet child. You should read about jquery and javascript if you want to make something custom rather then copy paste scripts.

Answer (score 1):

WHen learning jQuery it is easy to focus on needing an ID for everything since ID selectors are very specific. Using ID's can get complicated to code when faced with multiple scenarios for each group of ID. However there are many ways to match different elements using other methods that can greatly simplify code without needing to use any ID.

For example adding a wrapper around your buttons and around the content items in your demo and code can be written using `index()` method:

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id=a style="display:none">1</diV>
  <div id=b style="display:none">2</diV>
  <div id=c style="display:none">3</diV>
  <div id=d style="display:none">4</diV>
</div>
<div id="button_wrap">
  <input type=button value=1 id=w/>
  <input type=button value=2 id=x/>
  <input type=button value=3 id=y/>
  <input type=button value=4 id=z/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('#button_wrap input').click(function(){
      /* hide all content, show item that  matches index of this button*/
      $('#content').children().hide().eq( $(this).index() ).show()
    });
});
```

Adding classes to similar items is also a big helper for selectors

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/6UcDR/38/

API reference:

http://api.jquery.com/index/

http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Spend some time looking through the various traversal methods and examples in the API. Understanding what the various traverses do will help you generate more dynamic layouts and user interfaces

Comment: I would have gone about this the same way, +1

Comment: I've tried this code here is and clicking on the buttons doesn't display anything.

I've put this in the loop and the `<?php the_ID(); ?>` just returns a number. 

`<script type="text/javascript">
$('#button_wrap input').click(function(){
  $('#content').children().hide().eq( $(this).index() ).show()
})
</script>`

and here is the HTML part of it 

http://pastebin.com/epPj24ka

Comment: make sure you wrap all you jquery in `document.ready` . jsfiddle does this automatically  http://api.jquery.com/ready/ I updated answer with `ready` wrapper

Comment: read this for better understanding of why:  http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Comment: I tried the following 

`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#button_wrap input').click(function(){
  $('#content').children().hide().eq( $(this).index() ).show()
})
};
</script>`

Comment: look in browser console for errors. you have syntax error, not closing all braces. jshint.com can help too

Comment: I'm inexperienced with javascript and over 5 errors came up. I just added the document ready but I'm pretty sure I didn't do it correctly. Could you please check that?

Comment: you will have to learn how to resolve syntax problems and various errors. 5 errors seems high. Did you include jQuery.js? Create demos in jsfiddle for code that doesn't work. look at jshint.com

Comment: I'm using wordpress, jQuery would have been already called when the page loads. 

This is the code 
`<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function () { $('#button_wrap input').click(function(){ $('#content').children().hide().eq( $(this).index() ).show() }) }; </script>`

Comment: match all your braces... if you open one it has to be closed. I gave you a syntax validator you can use

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".contet").each( function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
$(".tab").on("click", function() {
  var s = $(this).attr("id");
  var g = $("#"+s+".contet").html();
  $(".content").html(g);
});
```

[Working Fiddle With Pure jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/AR6nr/1/)

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for. Again, I want the content on the top. As you can see from my original post with the Dynamic Content Displayed and images example. 

I am looking for an extremely simply script, something similar to what I've provided with jsfiddle. I don't want to add other plugins or sources and such.

Comment: Now See My Answer! And Also Accept It!

Comment: This is looking better, but I am having trouble getting this to work on my page. The elements are unclickable there. Also, how would I go about making all the content invisible on startup, and only the first one visible.

Comment: "the first one visible" i already have done it in fiddle. Copy the code from there. and also, what error are you getting? you do not have to change the classnames and ids! otherwise, if you want to then please add the HTML code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="../../jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../demos.css">
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
    </script>
<div class="demo">

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Image1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Image2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Image3</p>
    </div>
        <div id="tabs-4">
        <p>Image4</p>
    </div>
 <div id="tabs-5">
        <p>Image5</p>
    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I need to click on the images to get content to display. Not the other way around.